# VirtualBox crashes due to ALSA ("Invalid value for card")

Tags: virtualbox, alsa, segmentation-fault

For some reason whenever I try to load VirtualBox using `VBoxHeadless` inside a remote SSH shell session, it crashes with the following error:

```
$ VBoxHeadless -s myvm
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 5.1.2_OSE
(C) 2008-2016 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.

ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1701:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1701:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is there a way to fix or at least work around this problem?  I don't really need sound support.

Comment: There are only a few ways to fix a segfault, and the first two involve fixing the code yourself, and reporting the problem to the developers.  Sadly, asking on SE is never on that list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why this error occurs, but as an interim solution, I managed to work around the problem by disabling sound altogether:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm myvm --audio none
```

where `myvm` is the name of the virtual machine.